# How to assign icon to script file that just got created in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, icons, assets, system.reflection

I am trying to figure out on how to assign icon to a script file that just got created in Unity, but with no success so far.
I created this EditorWindow class that allows me to create a new c# class with some custom template.

After I created the file I save the asset like this

```
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(filePath, ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

After the script is created I want to also assign the custom icon automatically. Something like if you create a script named `GameManager`, unity automatically assigns custom icon for that script file.
I created `AssetPostprocessor` class that checks if the new asset is created under a specific path change the icon for that file.
The problem is that when I tried to test this Unity crashed for me. So I am running out of ideas a bit..

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Script_Importer : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPreprocessAsset()
    {
        if (assetPath.Contains("Scripts/CustomScripts/"))
        {
            AssetImporter asset = (AssetImporter)assetImporter;
            var obj = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(assetPath) as UnityEngine.Object;
            AssignLabel(obj);
        }
    }

    void AssignLabel(UnityEngine.Object obj)
    {
        Texture2D tex = EditorGUIUtility.IconContent("Script_Icon").image as Texture2D;
        Type editorGUIUtilityType = typeof(EditorGUIUtility);
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        object[] args = new object[] { obj, tex };
    editorGUIUtilityType.InvokeMember("SetIconForObject", bindingFlags, null, null, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just stating the obvious. A try catch that dumps the exception to a text file might help you identify why unity is crashing, and what to do to get this working.

Comment: I have tried something similar in the past, but ran into a Unity bug that never really got fixed. Perhaps it's of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933372/programmatically-setting-and-saving-the-icon-associated-with-an-imported-asset